# Subprocess Error with "pip install rnanorm" Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. exit code: 1

Tags: build, subprocess

I'm on a windows 10 running python 3.9 64 bit
I'm trying to install this software in jupyter notebooks: https://pypi.org/project/rnanorm/
using the command "pip install rnanorm"

When I use the command "pip install rnanorm"

I get the following error, even though I have tried installing/updating numpy:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
```

```
  [34 lines of output]
  # pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
  # pysam: htslib mode is shared
  # pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
  '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  # pysam: htslib configure options: None
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\cathe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0f0iqe9_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\cathe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0f0iqe9_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\cathe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0f0iqe9_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\cathe\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0f0iqe9_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 383, in <module>
    File "<string>", line 79, in run_make_print_config
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
    File "C:\Users\cathe\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error`

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.
```

`note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.`